# Additional properties are not allowed ('environment', 'image', 'ports', 'container_name' were unexpected)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I am trying to run docker-compose but facing the below error. Can someone help?

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
     # ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elg
  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline/
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
      - type: bind
        source: ./data/
        target: /usr/share/logstash/data 
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
   #command: --config.reload.automatic
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elg
    
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elg
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
networks:
  elg:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  elasticsearch:

  mysql_db_container:
     container_name: mysql
     image: mysql:latest
     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
     environment: 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
        volumes: 
        type: bind
        source: ./home/practical-devsecops/docker-elg/my-db
        target: /var/lib/mysql
        
        ports: "3306:3306"
           
networks:
  elg:
    driver: bridge
  adminer_container:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer:latest
    environment: 
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: mysql_db_container
      ports: "8080:8080"
        
networks:
  elg:
    driver: bridge
```

volumes.adminer value Additional properties are not allowed ('environment', 'image', 'ports', 'container_name' were unexpected)
volumes.mysql value Additional properties are not allowed ('target', 'image', 'environment', 'source', 'command', 'volumes', 'container_name', 'type', 'ports' were unexpected)

Answer (score 4):

The issue you have is with the indentation around the mysql_db_container service The lines:

```
networks:
  elg:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

in between your grafana and mysql_db_container service specification is indented incorrectly. As it at present, they break the service specification and cause docker-compose to complain.

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file is mixing top-level blocks together.  Abstracting away all of the content, you have:

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  elasticsearch: { a: service definition }
  logstash: { a: service definition }
  grafana: { a: service definition }
networks:
  elg: { a: network definition }
volumes:
  elasticsearch: # null
  mysql_db_container: { a: service definition } # <----
networks:
  elg: { a: network definition }
  adminer_container: { a: service definition } # <----
networks:
  elg: { a: network definition }
```

Notice that `mysql_db_container` is under `volumes:`, and `adminer_container` is under `networks:`.  Compose ignores that they have a Compose service layout and the word "container" in their name, and tries to interpret them according to the top-level block they're under.

You should be able to restructure this to have `services:`, `networks:`, and `volumes:` at the top level once only:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch: { a: service definition }
  logstash: { a: service definition }
  grafana: { a: service definition }
  mysql_db_container: { a: service definition } # <----
  adminer_container: { a: service definition } # <----
networks:
  elg: { a: network definition }
volumes:
  elasticsearch: # null
```

(You can also safely remove `networks:` everywhere in the file.  Compose will create a network named `default` with default settings and attach the various containers to it.  You also shouldn't usually need `container_name:` in routine use.  There are a couple of duplicated `depends_on:` blocks as well and you can clean these up, but I don't think they'll cause problems.)